# How to send an eof to a process/server in pwntools?

Tags: python, c, eof, pwntools

I was trying to make read return 0 in a program (the one in the while loop), and then execute the second read properly, which worked perfectly by hand, with `CTRL-D`. However I wanted to do the same in pwntools (`p = process("./test")`). I have already tried to send the eof character with `p.sendline("\x04")` but didn't work. The program took the input like `"\x0a\x04"`. `p.send()` doesn't change anything. This is my test program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char buf[24];
   while(1) {
      if(read(0,buf,16)==0) {
         break;
      }
   }
   read(0,buf,16);
   return 0;
}
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: `EOF` is not a character. It's a signal. As in ... if you ask your friend how much money there is in their bank account and they answer "Go to hell" ... "Go to hell" is not an amount of money in a bank account. Simply close `p` and the environment you're in will probably send the right signal to your listening program.

Comment: @pmg Ok cool thanks, but if we imagine the program continues afterwards, I can't just close the program. Is there a way to make read just return null and continue? This works with `CTRL-D`

Comment: `have already tried to send the eof character with p.sendline("\x04")` what is `p`?

Comment: Don't close the program you've shown. Close `p` ... whatever that is ... like typing `Ctrl+D` "closes" the keyboard.

Comment: I edited the question, maybe it's more clear now

Comment: maybe `p.release()`, `p.disconnect()`, `p.close()`, `p.destroy()`, `p.hangup()`... don't know "pwntools" ... maybe `process("./test")` isn't the right tool for what you are trying to do

Comment: @pmg I love the bank account analogy, but it's probably a bad idea to use the word "signal".  Too much baggage, and may cause confusion since `^C` does send a signal while `^D` does not.  Perhaps say that EOF is an indicator, or a flag, or something.

Comment: Noted, and agreed @WilliamPursell

Comment: From [what I can tell](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/tubes/processes.html), by default, pwnlib.tubes.process.process uses a pipe for for spawned process's standard input. If standard input is a pipe, `read` won't return 0 until the other end of the pipe has been closed and all data in the pipe has been read. However, You can tell it to use a PTY (pseudo terminal) for standard input, which would allow interactive control as though the input was being entered from a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of connection.

If it is a pipe or a socket, there is no other way than closing the connection.

But if it is a pseudo-terminal (you can enforce it in pwntools by using `process(..., stdin=PTY)`), you can use the terminal line editing capabilities of the operating system (see [`termios(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) for the description of canonical mode), you can send it an EOF mark with `p.send(b'\4')` (i.e. Ctrl+D).

So your final code should look something like:

```py
from pwn import *

p = process('./test', stdin=PTY)
p.send(b'\4')  # mind the b before binary data literal (text is not bytes)

# then something else maybe
p.interactive()
```